# If/else statement - make "else" same as before state

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, conditional-statements, statements

I have certain -select- option on my future web page where costumers have option to select between 2 values (value white and value black). These options change how some content look. Value white is default option and i don't need to change there anything when user chooses that one. Value black is additonal one and when customer selects it, some visual things change. I do those changes using jquery and statemants if/else (if value is selected do that or else...).

My question now is, is there any easy way to make else statment "delete" all those changes from "if" statement and return everything to default state, without much writing same things over and over again?

Example of code (this is just simple example tho):

```
    $("#optioncolor").change(function(){
    if ($("#optioncolor").val() == "#262626") {
    $("#row").css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)");
    $("#botbor").css("background", "white");
    } else {
    ???
    }
});
```

With else, i want do delete entire if statement!

I hope you understand.
Thanks.

Comment: Without specific code example I don't see how can we help... Further, if the `else` is getting executed it means that the `if` wasn't, so there's nothing to "revert".

Comment: What do you want to get deleted when else is getting executed ?

Comment: there is something known as removeAttr try working over this on your else block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Chetan V** already pointed out, use `removeAttr('style')` to clear any previously defined styles on the elements.

```
$("#optioncolor").change(function(){
    if ($("#optioncolor").val() == "#262626") {
        $("#row").css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)");
        $("#botbor").css("background", "white");
    } else {
        $("#row").removeAttr('style')
        $("#botbor").removeAttr('style')
    }
});
```

Comment: That's something I was looking for. This does work and it saves me a lot of time. Thank you and thanks Chetan V! I accepted your answer :)